# Failed _debugLocked assertion when calling Navigator.push() in simple app

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a simple first app, centered around a set of TabBar tabs.  I want one of these tabs to contain a button which launches a modal when clicked, which seems to necessitate pushing a widget to the navigation stack.

The tab stuff works fine, but attempting to push the modal widget results in `'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2330 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.`, which is used to "prevent re-entrant calls to push, pop, and friends".

Does anything about this approach look obviously wrong?  I substituted a Text widget for the actual modal in an attempt to simplify tracking down the source of the error.

```dart
class SessionsView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Timer(),
        ]);
  }
}

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Timer> createState() => _Timer();
}

class _Timer extends State<Timer> {

  Duration timerDuration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerDuration = Duration(seconds: 10);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        TimerIconButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TimerIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: launchTestModal(context),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse),
    );
  }
}

launchTestModal(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Text('something');
        },
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ));
}
```

Comment: It was a dumb mistake in the button: `onPressed: launchTestModal(context)` should have been onPressed: () {launchTestModal(context);}

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`

code snippet

```
launchTestModal(BuildContext context) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Text('something');
          },
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        ));
  });
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SessionsView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Timer(),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Timer> createState() => _Timer();
}

class _Timer extends State<Timer> {
  Duration timerDuration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerDuration = Duration(seconds: 10);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        TimerIconButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TimerIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: launchTestModal(context),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse),
    );
  }
}

launchTestModal(BuildContext context) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Text('something');
          },
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        ));
  });
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SessionsView(),
    );
  }
}
```